# iPhone app sharing data over both Wifi networks

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

I need to make an iPhone application which connects to a first Wifi network, receives some files from a specific device and then sends these files to a computer being connected on another Wifi network.

I see two possible approaches :
 1. to send the files to the computer, my app disconnects from the first Wifi network and connects again to the second network
 2. my iPhone app is able to connect itself to two different Wifi networks.

I believe the second solution above is not possible on iOS and the first one needs to use private APIs.

Do you see for other solutions for me to receive data from a device connected to a Wifi network and then send data to another device connected to another Wifi network ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot programmatically modify the selected WiFi on iOS without using private API. I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387423/connect-to-wifi-programmatically-in-ios) describes what you want.

I think it is very unlikely for Apple to change this, therefor I suggest using a web service to upload the data to and a push notification to the computer to tell it to download the data once it has finished uploading.

Comment: Thanks. My app does not need to be published on the Appstore elsewhere I could use private APIs. However the app needs to be installed on several devices in ad-hoc mode and the requirement to have the devices jailbroken such as the app is installed in the specific Application folder with ssh is more annoying for me. I think this issue is insurmountable for my users.

Comment: Using a Web service is not possible because there is no Internet connection available on the Wifi network I'm concerned with.