# How to get available all wifi network name Listing in swift

Tags: swift

I have a simple question but I don't know how to implement this. I need to create an app that can get all list of available wifi networks names and information when the user clicks on some network iPhone have to connect to this network. Can I do this? and How. Please Help me.

Answer (score 2):

answer is no in some case you get list of nearer wifi but can't connect.(its also not advisable)

---

details :-

prefer below links to get wifi list:

- [How to get available wifi network name in iOS using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715055/how-to-get-available-wifi-network-name-in-ios-using-swift/41964782)
- [iOS Get list of all WiFi networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681984/ios-get-list-of-all-wifi-networks)

some similar questions for reference:

- [Connect to WiFi programmatically in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387423/connect-to-wifi-programmatically-in-ios)
- [connect to a specific wifi programmatically in ios with a given SSID and Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626733/connect-to-a-specific-wifi-programmatically-in-ios-with-a-given-ssid-and-passwor)
- [Where do I find iOS Obj-C code to scan and connect to wifi (private API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725553/where-do-i-find-ios-obj-c-code-to-scan-and-connect-to-wifi-private-api)
- [Programmatically auto-connect to WiFi iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613344/programmatically-auto-connect-to-wifi-ios)

The most interesting answer seems to be in the first link which points to a GitHub project: [wifiAssociate](https://github.com/devinshively/wifiAssociate). However someones in the third link explains that this doesn't work anymore with iOS8 so you might have hard time getting it running.
Furthermore the iDevice must be jailbroken.

i hope it will help you :)

Comment: How to get available all wifi network name Listing in app

Comment: read updated answer may be some methods are deprecated so use accordingly